# How does Axton's Gemini skill (two turrets) affect the recharge from retrieving turrets?

Tags: borderlands-2

Can I use the extra turret to recharge the skill quicker (or instantly)? Does the extra turret split the recharge so that I'd have to retrieve both turrets for the same amount of recharge as one previously provided? Or is the second turret just ignored altogether?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the bad news is naw it doesnt work like this

if you reclaim one turret other will be reclaimed automatically.
Also if you throw one turret and throw the other one 10 seconds later both will go simultaneously, and the time is counted from the first throw.

:( so its not that good as it sounds.